# xcode mac designed for iphone app run in wrong window size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compatibility, apple-silicon

i have developed my iphone app in xcode and it runs fine in iphone,
i want to also run it on my m2 mac with the mac (designed for iphone app) option
but when it runs the window doesnt have the "iphone" frame window, but it opens it in a weird 500x300 non resizable window that messes up all screens !

If i add ipad as supported destination and run it (designed for ipad)
it open a "ipad-like" frame windows and everything works as it should, but i dont want to add ipad as a supported destination to my app !

Any idea about how can i fix this ?

[image]
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: is this an older, pre-Xcode 15 project?

Comment: yes it is, project created with xcode 11, i am now using xcode 15

Comment: I'd create a new project, and then compare the two projects. I'd look at the project file and the storyboard...